# how to fix this issue Failed to load plugin: filemanager from url /filemanager/plugin.min.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",
      theme: "modern",
      width: 680,
      height: 300,
      plugins: ["advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak", "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking", "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"],
      toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
      toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
      image_advtab: true,
      external_filemanager_path: "/filemanager/",
      filemanager_title: "myPHPnotes",
      external_plugins: {
         "filemanager": "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"
      },
      visualblocks_default_state: true,
   });
});
```

Comment: Most likely it means it can't find the file at `/filemanager/plugin.min.js` Double check the path and casing. Try to load that file directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
external_filemanager_path: "filemanager/",
"filemanager": "filemanager/plugin.min.js"
```

Try without slashes